# colorbox previous and next not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

I have 2 scripts that seem to be in conflict, so that the Previous and Next buttons do not show on the Colorbox overlay (the Close button is there and works fine). My css calls are correct and I rule that out as an issue anyway by adding:

```
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext {display:block !important; overflow:visible;}
```

which then shows the next and previous graphic buttons but they do not function when clicked (this has since been deleted).

The Chrome javascript console gives me this message:

```
Error: cboxElement missing settings object jquery.colorbox.js:204
```

Lastly, if I comment out Animated Repsonsive Grid, the controls perform correctly on the Colorbox overlay.

I did try to put the Colorbox script in noConflict mode, but that only disabled the Animated Responsive Grid.

You can see my test page at http://www.flowerlandshop.com/photostest.html

edit: here is my head code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.26633.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fallback.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fallback.css" />
    <![endif]-->


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.flowerlandshop.com/css/colorbox.css" />
            <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1', open:true});
                });
            </script>
```

and here is the js call at bottom of the page for the animated responsive grid:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gridrotator.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                $(function() {

                    $( '#ri-grid' ).gridrotator( {
                rows : 4,
                columns : 9,
                maxStep : 2,
                interval : 2500,
                animType: 'random',
                preventClick: false,
                w1100 : { //ipad landscape
                    rows : 6,
                    columns : 6
                },
                w1024 : { //ipad portrait
                    rows : 6,
                    columns : 6
                },
                w768 : { //iphone landscape
                    rows : 2,
                    columns : 6
                },
                w480 : {  //iphone portrait
                    rows : 5,
                    columns : 4
                },
                w320 : {
                    rows : 5,
                    columns : 4
                },
                w240 : {
                    rows : 6,
                    columns : 4
                },
            } );

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `open:true`into colorbox's options. Works for me.

PS: provide please your js where u use colorbox and a cut of html

Comment: adding open:true makes an overlay slide with controls appear when I refresh the page, but they do not function, and when I collapse that slide and click on another image in the grid, the resulting overlay slide has no controls.